# Proper use of pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, aiohttp, pool

I have an asynchronous function that checks if the token is valid. I want to count how many working and non-working tokens. Also I use aiomultiprocess. The code below works, but I think I did it wrong. Can you point out my mistakes?

```
import aiohttp
from aiomultiprocess import Pool



async def check_valid_tokens(token, valid=0, invalid=0):
    headers = {
        'authorization': f'{token}',
    }
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url="url", headers=headers) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                valid += 1
            elif response.status == 401:
                invalid += 1
    return valid, invalid


async def check_document(file):
    valid = 0
    invalid = 0

    async with Pool() as pool:
        async for result in pool.map(check_valid_tokens, tokens):
            valid += result[0]
            invalid += result[1]
    return valid, invalid
```

Comment: "The code below works, but I think I did it wrong" What do you mean? What do you think is wrong? We don't even know what constitutes correct behavior.

Comment: it seems to me that the arguments valid and invalid should be in the map and will not be repeated in two functions

Comment: I'm an idiot and I can't explain, sorry if I don't understand